# How can i connect express api outside of docker to mongodb that inside docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

i create a docker-compose that can connect express and mongo (container express to mongo container) but i have trouble i can't connect express api that run out side of my docker to mongodb that run inside docker how can i connect ?

i tried to find to change mongoURI in express but i still can't connect it and then i tried to find some example but still can't

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: supermongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

this is mongoURI form my json file

```
"mongoURI": "mongodb://supermongo:27017/development"
```

and it always show this Error

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [supermongo:27018] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND supermongo supermongo:27018]
```

> Already fix it i change mongoURI to
>   mongodb://localhost:27017/development because it already forward to my
>   localhost thanks :D

Comment: Use ip of the machine where supermongo container is running `ip:27017` in your url.